# Magento 1.7.0.2 custom payment methods not showing on frontend checkput page

Tags: magento, module, payment-gateway

Magento 1.7.0.2 custom payment method not showing on front end checkout page

I am trying to create a custom payment method to connect to an external payment provider.
But no mater what module I am building or using, my new payment method will not show on front end, in the checkout page.
I have tried the create payment module tutorial at:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module 
and the really great tutorial at:

http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/

The modules are built and I can see and configure them on admin panel.
But the new payment option will not show on front end.

Following some tips I found on the topic I have tried:

- Making sure that the currency is set correctly in both modules and
  store.
- make sure that allowed countries are allowed in module
- I am working with cache disabled and just to make sure flushing it every time a I
  change something, (either through system or directly at var/cache folder).
- I have disabled two other modules I previously installed:
  CurrencyManager & Skipstep1.

I will greatly appreciate any help, as this is the only thing left for me to get my store online :), and I could not find a solution for a few days now.
Thank you

Comment: Have you found it. It works for me. On config xml you should rename mygateway to your module name.

Comment: Hi Flakerim, thanks for the reply. I wound up re-installing a fresh Magento out of the box, and re-added my overrides and configs. After that all worked great. It is still a mystery what went wrong...